# How to programmatically add items on DropDownEdit asp.NET (VB)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, devexpress

I made a webForm in which I simply put a DropDownList like this :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <dx:ASPxDropDownEdit runat="server"></dx:ASPxDropDownEdit>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I programmaically add item in it ? I would like to display simple text (like "Item1", "Item2, ...) when clicking on the down arrow of this element.

Comment: did you try anything at all? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I need to use ComboBox item instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From:** [ASPxDropDownEdit Overview](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument11116)

> The ASPxDropDownEdit represents an editor containing an edit box to
>   display the editor value and a specific button, that opens a dropdown
>   window whose content can be templated. The main purpose of the
>   ASPxDropDownEdit is to allow you to define its value based upon the
>   value(s) of other control(s) integrated into the editor's
>   DropDownWindowTemplate.

As per the documentation, you can not use it as like a combo box control. I suggest you use [ASPxComboBox](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument11653), which let you implement this functionality in easy way.

If you desperate to implement the DropDownEdit control then you need to create its DropDownWindowTemplate programmatically. Follow the below approach and you can try to implement what you want to accomplish.

// Assign DropDownWindowTemplate property to custom template

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ASPxDropDownEdit1.DropDownWindowTemplate = new CustomTemplate();
}
```

//Template class that implement ITemplate interface.

```
public class CustomTemplate:ITemplate
{
    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        ASPxListBox listBox = new ASPxListBox();
        listBox.Items.Add("Item 1");
        listBox.Items.Add("Item 2");
        listBox.Items.Add("Item 3");
        container.Controls.Add(listBox);
    }
}
```

Refer this:
[Creating Web Server Control Templates Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289501(v=vs.71).aspx)